# Which recursive call is the most efficient?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

So I have a task to program a method for finding the n'th power of x with the help of recursion. The base case is that if n = 0, then x^n = 1.
If n is an odd number, then x^n = x*(x^2)^((n-1)/2).
If n is an even number, then x^n = (x^2)^(n/2). Not sure if you need this information, but just added it in case.

My problem is that I have two ways to use the recursive calls, but I am not sure which one is the "best" one or most efficient one.

Here is the method:

```
public double findNthPowerOfXV2(int n, double x){
        if(n == 0){                                                                                     
            return 1;                                                                                   
        }else if(!(n % 2 == 0)){                                                                        
            return x * findNthPowerOfXV2(((n-1)/2), x) * findNthPowerOfXV2(((n-1)/2), x);               
            //return x * findNthPowerOfXV2(((n-1)/2), x * x) also works, but not sure which is best
        }else{

            return findNthPowerOfXV2(n/2, x) * findNthPowerOfXV2(n/2, x);
            //return findNthPowerOfXV2(n/2, x * x) also works, but not sure which is best
        }
}
```

The line of code that is commented out, to me, looks better and more correct. I am not sure if I am wrong when I am saying that the line that is commented out makes the method do fewer loops?
However when I test the time it takes to complete the method, the line that is not commented out is faster than the one who is. Even though it has two recursive calls, which I would guess results in more loops?

This is the code I use to test the time usage of the method:

```
Date start2 = new Date();
int rounds2 = 0;
double time2;
Date stop2;
do {
  main.findNthPowerOfXV2(5000, 1.001);
  stop2 = new Date();
  ++rounds2;
}while(stop2.getTime() - start2.getTime() < 1000);
time2 = (double) stop2.getTime() - start2.getTime() / rounds2;
System.out.println(time2);
```

When I use the line that is not commented out I get `1.597890920672E12`
When I use the line that is commented out I get `1.597915039728E12`

So which one is more correct to use? I am looking for an explanation of which one is better to use and why. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Those times are practically identical; in fact I'd expect more difference between runs of the _same_ algorithm. And you are also measuring the time it takes to construct a `new Date()` which might well be bigger than your own function. Better to do a fixed number of iterations, tweaked such that it takes a few seconds to run; and then repeat _that_ multiple times because the first time the code might not have been JITted yet. Benchmarking is hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the commented-out version is, in principle, more efficient. Consider how many calls we make, for example, when computing `2^4`.

First the inefficient version:

```
- 2^4
  - 2^2
    - 2^1
      - 2^0
      - 2^0
    - 2^1
      - 2^0
      - 2^0
  - 2^2
    - 2^1
      - 2^0
      - 2^0
    - 2^1
      - 2^0
      - 2^0
```

If we double `n`, this tree doubles in size, so this algorithm is `O(n)`. Another way to see this is to *assume* that it's correct for the recursive calls, and then show that it's correct for the base call as well. In this case, we are making two recursive calls that each do `n/2` operations (by assumption) so the base call does `2 * n/2 = n` operations.

And now the efficient version:

```
- 2^4
  - 2^2
    - 2^1
      - 2^0
```

Here, if we *double* the value of `n` the tree increases 1 in size, so this is `O(log n)`.

I'll leave the rigorous proofs to the reader. In both cases I'm ignoring odd values of `n` because they don't matter in the big-O scheme of things.

---

The fact that you are not able to measure this difference probably says more about your benchmarking code:

- Constructing a `new Date` object invokes the memory manager, might trigger the garbage collector, and probably performs a system call to fetch the current time from the operating system, so it might be taking longer than the actual function you're testing.
- The Java runtime (I assume this is Java) employs a just-in-time compiler that only kicks in when a function is called multiple times, so the first time it runs, the result is not representative.
- Maybe the compiler is smart enough to recognize that the function is pure and that you're doing two calls with the same arguments, so it might not be as inefficient as it looks.